# What should I do? Reformatting Encrypted Hard Disk

Tags: encryption

I have a serious problem. Last night I was updating my Ubuntu system to the newest one, 15.04 on one of my two computers, but I was a little bit under the influence so I chose to encrypt the hard disk with a password that I am not sure anymore how it was spelled.

As a result that computer now will only start if I am able to recover the password which I failed to get it right even after many trials.

I tried to take out the HDD and connect it with a SATA cable I have and format with my computer but that also doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "format with my computer ... doesn't work". Tell us very clearly, what tools are used, and what errors you get.

Comment: I tried to do a quick-format on windows 8 first with another computer (not the one with the problem). I did that by getting the HDD from the encrypted partition out of the computer then using a sata cable to connect it to to my other computer.....  I am using the quick format option from my other computer that has dual-boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me once. If it is OK with you to clear everything, here is what you do:

- Get a windows(Xp if possible) live cd or usb
- boot from it and delete the partition(make a new one if you want)
- fresh install Ubuntu(and if you do encrypt it, don't forget to write down your password)

Note: since you are new, if my answer solved your problem, dont forget to tick the green button on the left top of my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. Is getting an windows xp live cd or usb really necessary? 

I have another computer that has an windows 8 + ubuntu dual boot on it. Can't I just format without using the quick format option? Is there any easier/faster manner? I could use my SATA cable to connect it to my other computer and then try to delete the partition from there? What's the most effective way to do it? 

btw, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: I didn't know Windows XP had a live CD/USB.

Comment: Thanks Kiduso Amare I tried everything and it finally worked for me.